# Join lists as a result of append in Loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have lists as results of an append, and I want to join the lists:

```
for info_api in data:
    unit_id = info_api['unitId']
    porcentagem = round(info_api['similarityScore'] * 100)
    apto = info_api['unitNumber']

    final_info_api = [apto, unit_id, porcentagem]

    final_data.append(final_info_api)

print("Result:", final_data)

# output: 
# Result: [['5', 140382, 62], ['55', 140413, 61]]
# Result: [['105', 140442, 57], ['51', 140410, 56]]
```

What I want is to join the lists that came from the append:

Result: `['5', 140382, 62], ['55', 140413, 61],['105', 140442, 57], ['51', 140410, 56]`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `append`? You could use `extend` directly.

Otherwise if you need to keep final_data that way, you can flatten it for example with `sum(final_data, [])`